# Insert into from CTE

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, common-table-expression

```
  WITH DTL AS
  (SELECT CMPI_CODE,
         CMN_CDTY_MTRL,
         CMI_WT_FACTOR,
         CMI_CNTRCT_RATE,
         'PL',
         PRESENT_PRICE,
         TRM_CODE,
         ROUND(((NVL(PRESENT_PRICE,1)*CMI_WT_FACTOR) / CMI_CNTRCT_RATE),2) AS PL_FACTOR
  FROM VW_CMD_MATERIAL WHERE TRM_CODE = 41)
  INSERT iNTO IPA_PRCADJ_HDR(TRM_CODE,IPAPH_ADJ_FACTOR,IPAPH_AMT_CUR,IPAPH_REMARKS)
  SELECT TRM_CODE,SUM(PL_FACTOR) AS PL_FACTOR,((SUM(PL_FACTOR)*10)) AS AMT_CUR,'asdf' 
  FROM DTL GROUP BY (TRM_CODE);
```

showing an error `ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword`

Comment: i want to insert into IPA_PRCADJ_HDR

Answer (score 73, accepted):

This is the syntax to insert into a table from a CTE:

```
-- CREATE TABLE tmp ( tmp_id NUMBER(10) );

INSERT INTO tmp( tmp_id )
  WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 1 AS tmp_id FROM dual
  )
  SELECT tmp_id
  FROM cte;
```

Comment: Odd; curious, anyone know off hand which is the ANSI way of doing this? In Sql Server, the WITH clause goes at the very top of the query.

Comment: To my understanding there is no "ANSI way" to do this. ANSI allows CTEs only before SELECT statements. Allowing something similar in INSERT statements is a vendor specific extension that each vendor handles differently.

Answer (score 8):

Seems that Insert cannot be used as first statement after common table expression. Try this,

```
    INSERT iNTO IPA_PRCADJ_HDR(TRM_CODE,IPAPH_ADJ_FACTOR,IPAPH_AMT_CUR,IPAPH_REMARKS)
    SELECT * FROM 
    (

      WITH DTL AS
      (SELECT CMPI_CODE,
             CMN_CDTY_MTRL,
             CMI_WT_FACTOR,
             CMI_CNTRCT_RATE,
             'PL',
             PRESENT_PRICE,
             TRM_CODE,
             ROUND(((NVL(PRESENT_PRICE,1)*CMI_WT_FACTOR) / CMI_CNTRCT_RATE),2) AS PL_FACTOR
      FROM VW_CMD_MATERIAL WHERE TRM_CODE = 41
      )
      SELECT TRM_CODE,SUM(PL_FACTOR) AS PL_FACTOR,((SUM(PL_FACTOR)*10)) AS AMT_CUR,'asdf' 
      FROM DTL GROUP BY (TRM_CODE)
    );
```

Comment: Using Oracle11g.  Did not need wrap CTE in subquery.   CTE Expression follows immediately after insert.   Final projecting must be compatible target table columns (or column list).