# Valid GROUP BY query doesn't work when combined with INSERT INTO on Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I'm trying to write an INSERT INTO that does a some DISTINCT/GROUP BY work.  The query runs perfectly fine as a select statement, but will not work if it's wrapped into an INSERT INTO.

```
INSERT INTO MasterRecords
  (BatchRecordRecordID, SourceID, BatchID)
SELECT RecordID, SourceID, BatchID
FROM (
    SELECT RecordID, BatchID, 101 AS SourceID
    FROM BatchRecords
    WHERE BatchID = 150
    GROUP BY RecordID, BatchID
) BR
```

This earns me:

> SQL Error: ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression

But if I remove just the INSERT INTO code, it runs perfectly fine:

```
SELECT RecordID, SourceID, BatchID
FROM (
    SELECT RecordID, BatchID, 101 AS SourceID
    FROM BatchRecords
    WHERE BatchID = 150
    GROUP BY RecordID, BatchID
) BR
```

Results:

```
3   101 150
5   101 150
6   101 150
2   101 150
4   101 150
8   101 150
7   101 150
1   101 150
```

My assumption is that GROUP BY's are not allowed inside INSERT INTO select statements but I can find almost no documentation confirming this.

Comment: What happens if you run the inner most select on its own? (the derived table isn't really necessary anyway) I recall a bug where invalid `group by` clauses were not recognized in a derived table or sub-select. Don't remember the details though. Additionally, (unrelated): `150 AS BatchID` doesn't really make sense if you use `WHERE BatchID = 150`

Comment: Works the same if it's not re-wrapped with the outer select.  And the hard coded BatchID is just from my scratch area, that logic isn't critical.

Comment: If you add RecordID to the group by does it work?

Comment: Opps, `sourceID` then.  It just seems odd to me to have 3 non-aggregates   in the select and only 2 columns in the group by

Comment: Seems to depend on the Oracle version: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/105de/2 Btw: there is no PL/SQL in your question. PL/SQL is **only** used in stored procedures.

Comment: Updated with a more logical example.  It will not allow me to add non-column fields to the group by list

Comment: @Horse, this is correct, but I'm running it on Oracle.  On the chance that this is an oracle-only limitation, I don't want people thinking that what does and does not work here will necessarily work on SQL Server as well.

Comment: But PL/SQL has nothing to do with this. PL/SQL is not a synonym for "Oracle SQL". There is a clear distinct between SQL and PL/SQL in Oracle. The tag `sql` does not mean "SQL Server". Btw: your example also works fine on my local Oracle 12.1.0.1.0 version.

Comment: There are several bug reports on the Oracle support site regarding incorrect ora-979 and sub-queries. Try to run the statement with the `/*+ no_merge */` hint: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/sql_elements006.htm#BABCGJDI

Comment: No_Merge doesn't seem to have any impact

Comment: @Horse, I realize now that I have nested GROUP BY's elsewhere in other INSERT INTO statements, so this is definitely intermittent.  I'm just going to use DISTINCT for now and tackle it again if I actually can't get past it

Comment: I cannot reproduce on 12.1.0.2.0 either.  Can you add a more thorough test case, with full DDL, test data, and DML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Am I thinking wrong, but is not the sql below equal what you want to achieve?

```
INSERT INTO MasterRecords(BatchRecordRecordID, SourceID, BatchID)
SELECT DISTINCT RecordID, 101, 150
FROM BatchRecords
WHERE BatchID = 150
;
```

Comment: This does seem to be working now even though I was certain it wasn't working earlier

Answer (score 11):

I arrived here trying to solve a similar situation so it seems to me that this kind of problem still appears.

In my case, avoiding any optimizer transformation, did the trick.

I applied a NO_QUERY_TRANSFORMATION hint to the *"intoed"* SELECT statement and the error disappeared.

In the case of this question, I should rewrite it as:

```
INSERT INTO MasterRecords
  (BatchRecordRecordID, SourceID, BatchID)
SELECT /*+NO_QUERY_TRANSFORMATION*/ RecordID, SourceID, BatchID
FROM (
    SELECT RecordID, BatchID, 101 AS SourceID
    FROM BatchRecords
    WHERE BatchID = 150
    GROUP BY RecordID, BatchID
) BR
```

Comment: This works. It does however slow down the query by A LOT.

Comment: @TMob thanks for your feedback... This undesired side effect is due to NO_QUERY_TRANSFORMATION hint disable all query transformation that the optimizer can perform. There're situations in which it won't work other way. It's preferred that your query works without the hint!

Answer (score 0):

Wonder if it's an order of execution problem... does it work if you use a CTE?
CTE must first materialize thus resolve the group by...

```
  Insert INTO MasterRecords (BatchRecordRecordID, SourceID, BatchID)
   WITH BR AS (
    SELECT RecordID, 101 AS SourceID, 150 AS BatchID
    FROM BatchRecords
    GROUP BY RecordID, 101,150)
  Select RecordID, SourceID, BatchID FROM BR
```

or... why the group by and where clause in the first place doesn't seem to be doing anything since recordID isn't an aggregate and isn't part of the group by...

Insert into masterRecords (batchrecordRecordID, SourceID, BatchID)
SELECT recordID, 101, 150 from batchRecords

Comment: I'm not as familiar with Oracle as I am with SQL Server, does Oracle even support CTE's?

Comment: @TomHalladay: it did *long* before SQL Server

Comment: thanks to : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24008316/insert-into-from-cte updated my response.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved by automatically changing the value of a parameter (optimizer_features_enable). This value determines the optimizer version of the base, with 11 should not give that problem.