# SQLDeveloper Tuning Advisor with Compiler Hints

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I am trying to use the Oracle SQL Developer program to analyze a few queries that are taking an exponentially greater time to complete as the data pool gets large. In order to do so, I'm using the SQL Tuning Advisor to analyze the query/table structure to potentially create better indices and/or better queries.

Everything was going great until I analyzed my insert query. It has a /*+ no_merge(<>) */ hint in it since the sub-select used in the insert has aggregations that will cause a compiler "ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression" error. It is a well known bug already and I'm aware of that.

My problem is that the Tuning Advisor apparently ignores the hints and returns with the same error as you see above. I can still obtain an execution plan and can still run the query but I would like to use the advisor to get a better analysis.

A solution to my problem could either be a suggestion on how to alter my query to not use the no_merge hint or a tip on how to use the advisor with the hint.

I've already seen this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28354248/valid-group-by-query-doesnt-work-when-combined-with-insert-into-on-oracle) which shows one of the users commenting about the Oracle bug but it doesn't help my cause.

For discretionary purposes I can't just post the query on here. A description of the query is as follows:

```
Insert into tableX (
   cols...
)
select /*+ no_merge(<<alias>>) */
   <<alias>>.*
   otherCols...
from (
   select 
      cols...
      min(col1) as newName1,
      max(col1) as newName2
   from (
      select *
      from tableX
      where not exists (
         select 'x'
         from tableX
         where conditions...
      )
   ) group by
      cols...
) <<alias>>;
```

For @BobC in the comments...
[image: Version Number of the Oracle DB]

Comment: FWIW, the tuning advisor is a database feature, SQL Developer just provides a GUI for it

Comment: @thatjeffsmith yes I was noticing that under the covers it would show a script output so I figured it was just doing what I could do in sqlplus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing that 1) the bug appears to only affect `INSERT` statements and the `SELECT` in it should run just fine with the hint and 2) the advisor is unlikely to offer any help tuning the `INSERT` part specifically, you can simply run the adviser against the `SELECT` statement alone, with or without the hint.

Comment: Thank you. I did run the tuning advisor on just the inner select (the first select statement after the hint) and received some suggestions but I wanted to run it on the whole thing. If the tuner will probably not suggest much on inserts then I guess I don't need to worry about it then. Thanks for your help!

Comment: 1. Do you have the bug number? 2. Can you get an execution plan for your SQL?

Comment: @BobC check the link in the question.

Comment: @mustaccio. I'm sorry; I did check the link, but I could not find any reference to the bug number.

Comment: @BobC the link I was looking at [here](http://www.oracle-class.com/?p=1337) and the bug number: 9411496.

Comment: @MatthewZackschewski That bug is fixed in 12c, which you are apparently using

Comment: @BobC Do you have a reference for this? I just retested and I still am getting the same error. To verify, I tried it once with the /*+ no_merge(<<alias>>) */ hint and once without it. It worked with it and didn't work without it. The error that came up was the same error I wrote above. I would really like to just show you my query but I cannot so I'm sorry I couldn't be more informative.

Comment: @BobC ... and to answer your question from your first comment, I am able to get an execution plan on the query (using the hint no_merge) but I cannot use the Tuning Advisor which is where my problem lies... Please check the question as I've added a screenshot for you regarding the version # of my Oracle instance.

Comment: @MatthewZackschewski. You can reference the bug information via the MOS Note 9411496.8.  Since you are on 12.1.0.2, that bug should be fixed; so you must be hitting another. I would suggest contacting Oracle support and providing the appropriate diagnostics. Regarding the tuning advisor; I would say that the results you get from it can be questionable. So that is why I'd like to see the execution plan, and apply some "thinking". While a NO_MERGE hint might work around the bug, it could be causing sub-optimal executions plans.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137474/discussion-between-matthew-zackschewski-and-bobc).