# SQLAlchemy With Clause (CTE) with Insert is not compiling correctly for Oracle

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy, oracle12c

I'm attempting to generate the following contrived DML statement in SQLAlchemy for an Oracle 12CR1 database:

```
INSERT INTO baz (name, qty)
WITH bar AS (
    SELECT bar.name, bar.qty
    FROM bar
)
SELECT foo.name, bar.qty
FROM foo JOIN bar ON foo.name = bar.name
```

However, SQLAlchemy appears to be generating it out of order, like the following:

```
WITH bar AS (
    SELECT bar.name, bar.qty
    FROM bar
)
INSERT INTO baz (name, qty)
SELECT foo.name, bar.qty
FROM foo JOIN bar ON foo.name = bar.name
```

Executing this out of order fails with `ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected`.

My theory here is that SQLAlchemy is assuming the PostgreSQL syntax which is `WITH ... INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...` and is not respecting the Oracle syntax which is `INSERT INTO ... WITH ... SELECT ...`.

Is there any way to get this working with Oracle, or at least a way to modify the way an `insert().from_select()` is compiled?

To reproduce:

```
from sqlalchemy import (Table, Column, String, Integer,
                    MetaData, select, func)
from sqlalchemy.dialects import oracle


metadata = MetaData()

foo = Table('foo', metadata, Column('name', String))
bar = Table('bar', metadata, Column('name', String), Column('qty', Integer))
baz = Table('baz', metadata, Column('name', String), Column('qty', Integer))

with_bar = select([bar.c.name, bar.c.qty]).cte('bar')
sel = select([foo.c.name, with_bar.c.qty])
sel = sel.select_from(
        foo.join(with_bar, 
                 foo.c.name == with_bar.c.name
                 )
)

ins = baz.insert().from_select([baz.c.name, baz.c.qty], sel)
print ins.compile(dialect=oracle.dialect())
```

Comment: How about using subquery instead of CTE? `INSERT INTO baz (name, qty)
SELECT foo.name, bar.qty
FROM foo JOIN (SELECT bar.name, bar.qty
    FROM bar) bar ON foo.name = bar.name
` Of course you have to use proper sqlalchemy syntax, but result should work on both SQL dialects (Oracle/Postgresql)

Comment: @lad2025 It is a contrived example just to demonstrate that SQLAlchemy apparently doesn't respect the Oracle syntax.

Comment: I don't know what SQLAlchemy is (never heard of it till now). I did a quick Google search and I see what it is. Then I Googled "SQLAlchemy select SQL dialect" - you should try it too, you may find it helpful. The immediate guess is that you can specify what dialect you want SQLAlchemy to work in. Or... are you saying you have SQLAlchemy set up for the Oracle dialect, but it is simply not using it right?

Comment: @mathguy the code attempts to select the dialect on the last line...

Comment: @MatthewMoisen you should report an issue to SQLAlchemy bug tracker. It seems that (yet again) the Oracle CTE is the non-standard one https://stackoverflow.com/q/24008316/918959

Comment: @AnttiHaapala - lol, yes, I see it. As I said I am not familiar with the language, so I didn't try to read the code.

Comment: From the 2003 draft it'd seem that the Oracle way is actually the standard way: https://ronsavage.github.io/SQL/sql-2003-2.bnf.html#insert%20statement, but my reading might be, with a high probability, incorrect, and 2003 is quite old (but the latest I could find). Postgresql seems to actually accept both: `INSERT ... WITH ... SELECT ...` runs just as well.

Comment: And from the [Postgresql docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html): "INSERT conforms to the SQL standard, except that the RETURNING clause is a PostgreSQL extension, as is the ability to use WITH with INSERT". Also: "It is possible for the query (SELECT statement) to also contain a WITH clause. In such a case both sets of with_query can be referenced within the query, but the second one takes precedence since it is more closely nested." I wonder what the situation with SQL Server is.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need to do a custom rendering of the statement.
Here is code that helped me with this exact issue on another dialect (I've changed it to oracle)

```py
from sqlalchemy.ext.compiler import compiles
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import ClauseElement, Executable

class InsertFromSelect(Executable, ClauseElement):
    def __init__(self, table, select):
        self.table = table
        self.select = select

@compiles(InsertFromSelect, "oracle")
def visit_insert_from_select(element, compiler, **kw):
    return "INSERT INTO %s (%s)" % (
        compiler.process(element.table, asfrom=True, **kw),
        compiler.process(element.select, **kw)
    )

#target table to insert
table = sqlalchemy.Table('foo' MetaData=())
#statement with a CTE / WITH clause
baz = select().select_from(sqlalchemy.text('select * from bar').columns().cte())

#print or run the new statement, correctly ordered
print(
    InsertFromSelect(table,baz)
)
```

Essentially you'd be creating a new element `InsertFromSelect` which holds the query and the insert separately, and then a compilation visitor which renders them in the right spot.