# Creating multiple joins with phisical tables and CTEs

Tags: sql, oracle, common-table-expression

I'm a TSQL developer pretty new to Oracle.  I'm writing an insert query and the SELECT that populates this statement has various joins to both physical tables and a set of CTEs.  In SQL Server after defining my CTEs I could easily do an INSERT and create a SELECT based on the joins of both the physical and CTE tables as follows:

```
WITH TEST AS(
  SELECT VL FROM TABLE1 WHERE X = 5
),
TEST2 AS(SELECT VAL FROM TABLE4 WHERE Y =5)


INSERT INTO MYTABLE... 
SELECT VAL1, VAL2,...VALN FROM TEST INNER JOIN TABLE6 ON TEST.VL = 
 TABLE6.VL
INNER JOIN TEST2 ON ...
INNER JOIN TABLE10
```

I'm finding that this syntax doesn't apply in Oracle.  Tried a few things suggested by the community ([Insert into from CTE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24008316/insert-into-from-cte) ) but can't seem to find what I'm looking for...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps something like this?

```
insert into mytable
select val1, val2, ... valn
from (select vl from table1 where x = 5) t 
join table6 t6 on t6.vl = t.vl
join (select id, val from table4 where y = 5) t2 on t2.id = t.id
join table10 ...
```