# use CTE instead of subquery

Tags: mysql, subquery, common-table-expression

I tried to re-write a SQL query using `subquery` to one using `common table expression (CTE)`. The former is as below

```
select accounting_id, object_code, 'active', name
from master_data md
where md.id in (
    select MIN(md1.id)
    from master_data md1
    where md1.original_type = 'tpl'
    group by md1.object_code
);
```

The one below failed with

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'distinct_object_code_id' at line 9
```

```
with distinct_object_code_id(id) as (
    select MIN(md1.id)
    from master_data md1
    where md1.original_type = 'tpl'
    group by md1.object_code
) 
select md.accounting_id, md.object_code, 'active', md.name
from master_data md
where md.id in distinct_object_code_id;
```

This one also failed

```
with distinct_object_code_id as (
    select MIN(md1.id)
    from master_data md1
    where md1.original_type = 'tpl'
    group by md1.object_code
) 
select md.accounting_id, md.object_code, 'active', md.name
from master_data md
join distinct_object_code_id using(id)
;
```

whereas this one below works (by explicitly specify the column_list)

```
with distinct_object_code_id(id) as (
    select MIN(md1.id)
    from master_data md1
    where md1.original_type = 'tpl'
    group by md1.object_code
) 
select md.accounting_id, md.object_code, 'active', md.name
from master_data md
join distinct_object_code_id using(id)
;
```

I tried another one but it also failed (using subquery inside CTE)

```
with distinct_object_code_id as (
    select accounting_id, object_code, 'active', name
    from master_data md
    where md.id in (
        select MIN(md1.id)
        from master_data md1
        where md1.original_type = 'tpl'
        group by md1.object_code
)
select * from distinct_object_code_id;
```

The `MYSQL` database version is `8.0.29-0ubuntu0.20.04.3`.
what did I do wrong when using `CTE`?

**EDIT:**
I add a third part, in which I inserted the data from those queries above into another table `tpl_transferred_debtor` like below

```
with distinct_object_code_id as (
    select MIN(id) as id
    from master_data
    where original_type = 'tpl'
    group by object_code
), 
tmp_tpl_table as (
    select md.accounting_id, md.object_code, 'active', md.name
    from master_data md
    join distinct_object_code_id using(id)
)
insert into tpl_transferred_debtor(debtor_id, tpl_code, status, description)
select * from tmp_tpl_table;
```

This one failed with

```
Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the  manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right   syntax to use near 'insert into tpl_transferred_debtor(debtor_id,   tpl_code, status, description) sel' at line 12
```

I tried to write a simple one to check if the second CTE `tmp_tpl_table` and it is ok

```
with distinct_object_code_id as (
    select MIN(id) as id
    from master_data
    where original_type = 'tpl'
    group by object_code
), 
tmp_tpl_table as (
    select md.accounting_id, md.object_code, 'active', md.name
    from master_data md
    join distinct_object_code_id using(id)
)
select * from tmp_tpl_table;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first query fails because you cannot use IN to reference cte you have to join or the correct syntax for IN ie in (select..from cte)
Your second query fails because you didn't alias MIN(md1.id)
Your third query works because you referenced MIN(md1.id) by providing (ID)

Personally I prefer join..on over join..using

Comment: I edited my question to add one more step, which is inserting data from those queries above to another table, Could you help me with that?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24008316/insert-into-from-cte answer is for oracle but mysql is same.